# Error 16: Expression Too Complex - Nested Select Case

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a "Run-Time Error 16: Expression Too Complex" for the sencond code block.  I read online that the maximum allowed number of nested expressions is 8, but if nested statements are defined by every "Select Case," then I haven't yet hit that.  Is it possible it's because the Cases are dependent upon a variable?  The first code block shows the possible values of egapend, while the second shows the code that is returning the error.  Thanks in advance for your help.

First:

```
Select Case ge1e2
    Case Is <= 0
        Select Case ge2e3
            Case Is <= 0
                egap18a = 0
                egap18b = 0
            Case Is > 0
                egap18a = 0
                egap18b = ge2e3
                egapend = Sheet1.[z1IE]
        End Select
    Case Is > 0
        Select Case ge2e3
            Case Is <= 0
                egap18a = ge1e2
                egap18b = 0
                egapend = Sheet1.[z1CZ]
            Case Is > 0
                Select Case ge1e2
                    Case Is >= 180
                        egap18a = ge1e2
                        egap18b = ge2e3
                        egapend = Sheet1.[z1CZ]
                    Case Is < 180
                        egap18a = ge1e2
                        egap18b = ge2e3
                        egapend = Sheet1.[z1IE]
                End Select
        End Select
End Select
```

Second:

```
Dim e1length As Long
Dim e2length As Long
Dim cp121 As Boolean

e1length = DateDiff("d", Sheet1.[z1CZ], Sheet1.[z1DA])
e2length = DateDiff("d", Sheet1.[z1IE], Sheet1.[z1IF])

Select Case extendedgap
    Case True
        Select Case egapend
            Case Sheet1.[z1IE] 'end of egap is start of E2
                Select Case e2length 'was borrower employed by E2 for more than 6 months?
                    Case Is >= 180
                        cp121 = True
                    Case Is < 180
                        Select Case ge1e2 'if not, was there a gap between E1 and E2
                            Case Is > 1
                                cp121 = False
                            Case Else
                                Select Case DateDiff("d", Sheet1.[z1IE], Sheet1.[z1DA]) 'If not, was employment between E1/E2 6 mos?
                                    Case Is >= 180
                                        cp121 = True
                                    Case Is < 180
                                        cp121 = False
                                End Select
                        End Select
                End Select
            Case Sheet1.[z1CZ] 'end of egap is start of E1
                Select Case DateDiff("d", Sheet1.[z1CZ], Sheet1.[z1DA]) 'was borrower employed by E1 for at least 6 mos?
                    Case Is >= 180
                        cp121 = True
                    Case Is < 180
                        cp121 = False
                End Select
        End Select
```

Comment: (a) I assume there is another `End Select` immediately after the last line of your second code block (b) Ignore what I wrote as point b - I was silly

Comment: I think in concert with @YowE3K suggestion replace first `Select Case` (`Select Case extendedgap)` with `If extendedgap Then` ... then build your cases?

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K.  I may be misunderstanding your question, but the reason I have Case True is because if 'extendedgap' is false, I don't want any of the subsequent Select Cases to run, as they won't be relevant.

Comment: @khelm Yeah - my point (b) was absolutely stupid - I can only blame the fact that I am an hour overdue to go down and get my morning coffee

Comment: This really, really, really looks like `Select Case` abuse. each `Select` block has 2 branches. What you have is a very convoluted way to write a nested `If...Else...End If` block.

Comment: @YowE3K No problem - can't VBA without coffee!

Comment: ^^ and it may actually benefit from just setting `cp121` to either `True` or `False` to start with, and then using the `If` statements to just work out when it needs to be the opposite value.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Ok, thanks for saying that.  I'll go back and reconfigure!

Comment: @YowE3K That's a really good idea too, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's really just a big nested conditional structure. Don't use `Select...Case` for that. Use it e.g. when you're looking at some enum value:

```
Select Case MsgBox("Yes, no, or cancel?", vbYesNoCancel)
    Case vbYes
        'stuff
    Case vbNo
        'stuff
    Case vbCancel
        'stuff
End Select
```

---

**Refactoring step 1**: Turn all these 2-branch `Select...Case` blocks into `If...Else...End If` blocks. That should already take care of the "expression too complex" compile error.

**Refactoring step 2**: Implement Boolean assignments as such:

For example in <s>one place</s> *two places* you have:

> ```
> Select Case DateDiff("d", Sheet1.[z1IE], Sheet1.[z1DA]) 'If not, was employment between E1/E2 6 mos?
>     Case Is >= 180
>         cp121 = True
>     Case Is < 180
>         cp121 = False
> End Select
> ```

Replace that with:

```
cp121 = (DateDiff("d", Sheet1.[z1IE], Sheet1.[z1DA]) >= 180)
```

**Refactoring step 3**: Extract functions and procedures out of the `If` and `Else` branches where applicable; eliminate the duplicated branches, *Don't Repeat Yourself*.

Once you have something that works, take it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for further refactoring and simplification ideas.

Comment: That was SO helpful, thank you! You always give really thorough, conceptual answers and I appreciate them so much.